# SQL Query to count over a specific period

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

I'm having a table like this one:

```
-------------------------------
| NrOfVisitors | Year | Month |
-------------------------------
| 320          | 2009 | 1     |
-------------------------------
| 300          | 2009 | 2     |
-------------------------------
| 150          | 2010 | 1     |
-------------------------------
| 100          | 2010 | 2     |
-------------------------------
```

Now I want to count the visitors untill the 1st month of 2010.
When I say:

```
SELECT SUM(NrOfVisitors) As TotalVisitors FROM VisitorTable WHERE YEAR <= 2010 AND Month <= 1
```

Then I don't get the amount of visitors because then it doesn't count the visitors of 2009 month 2. So I'm missing 300 visitors with that query. So what I need is a query to count the NrOfVisitors untill 2010 month 1

Who can help me with this/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can simply use OR

```
WHERE YEAR <= 2010 OR MONTH <= 1
```

To be more general something like

```
WHERE YEAR < 2010 OR (YEAR = 2010 AND MONTH <=1)
```

Comment: That did the trick... Stupid, I didn't think of it... But thx :D

Comment: `WHERE YEAR <= 2010 OR MONTH <= 1` will match January 2011 (and 2012,...), which is probably not what OP wanted.

Comment: @eumiro, Indeed which is why i gave the more general example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(NrOfVisitors) As TotalVisitors
FROM VisitorTable
WHERE Year * 12 + Month <= 2010 * 12 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the:
AND Month <=1 ?
Edit: also make the:
WHERE YEAR <= 2010
to:
WhERE YEAR < 2010

That should work?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

`SELECT SUM(NrOfVisitors) As TotalVisitors FROM VisitorTable WHERE YEAR <= 2010 AND Month >= 1`
?

I just changed `Month <= 1` to `Month >= 1` because, well, 2 > 1.

That way, if you have more months, and if you don't want them counted, you can just change that constraint to reflect which months you want to count.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUM(NrOfVisitors) As TotalVisitors
FROM VisitorTable
WHERE YEAR <= 2010
OR (YEAR = 2010 AND MONTH = 1)